# Refills modal doesn't work on Rails 4.2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bourbon

I have installed [bourbon](http://bourbon.io), [neat](http://neat.bourbon.io) and [refills](http://refills.bourbon.io) and would like to use modal window. Following the instructions I made:

```
rails generate refills:import modal
```

I have the modal partial and added to the page

```
<%= render 'refills/modal' %>
```

The result:

[image]

Any idea what I missed? Thank you!

Comment: It looks like none of the JavaScript is working. Can you check the console in your browser and post the output here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following code to `application.js`

```
// require refills/modal
```

And then you need to add the following line to `application.scss`:

```
@import 'refills/modal';
```

That should do it.